# Sound not displaying inside script

Tags: javascript

I want to display a sound inside this script but it is not playing anything.

this is my code:

```
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        application_context: {
                shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
            },
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '1.99'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      var bleep = new Audio();
      bleep.src = "static/payment_success.m4a";
      bleep.currentTime=0;
      bleep.play();

some more code.....
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I'm a bit noob with javascript and don't really know how this could work. The sound is ok, it tested it and works perfectly, but not inside this code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also share html code, i mean where are you using onApprove

Comment: done @HimanshuPandey

Comment: bleep.setAttribute("src", "static/payment_success.m4a");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var bleep = new Audio();
  bleep.setAttribute("src", "static/payment_success.m4a");
  bleep.currentTime=0;
  bleep.play();
```